# Obtaining data from a table using foreign keys PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm trying to output a product from my products table using a foreign key that is in another table because the products are then saved into a user account.

**relational tables:**

```
useraccount > savedproduct < products
```

As many users can have many products and many products can have many users i have made up a table for the inbetween that holds only savedProductId, productId and user_id.

I want to output the product data from the savedproduct table that only has a certain user id attached, if that makes sense.

It practically works but shows all products (twice repeated) instead of just the ones that are under the user id in saved products, my code is here:

**NOTE:** Please do not say anything about injections, etc., i will be implementing that after i have everything worked out, thank you.

```
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM userAccount WHERE email='$user_check')";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
$column = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($column['admin'] != NULL){
    echo "<section class='userName'><h3>".$column['firstName']." ".$column['surname']."</h3></section>";
    echo "<section class='address'>".$column['addressLine1']."<br />".$column['addressLine2']."<br />".$column['county']."<br />".$column['country']."<br />".$column['postCode']."</section>";
    echo "<section class='email'><h3>".$column['email']."</h3></section>";
    echo "<section class='passwordUpdate'><a href='update.php?user_id=".$column['user_id']."'>Change Password</a></section>";
    echo "<section class='logout'><a href='extras/logoutProcess.php'>Logout</a></section>";
    echo "<hr />";
        </section>";
```

**Part where I am trying to output the saved products associated with the user id, etc:**

```
}else{
    $userIdent=$column['user_id'];
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT savedProduct.user_id, product.productName, product.productId, product.productImg, product.price FROM savedProduct, product WHERE savedProduct.user_id=$userIdent LIMIT 2";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    echo "<section class='userName'><h3>".$column['firstName']." ".$column['surname']."</h3></section>";
    echo "<section class='address'>".$column['addressLine1']."<br />".$column['addressLine2']."<br />".$column['county']."<br />".$column['country']."<br />".$column['postCode']."</section>";
    echo "<section class='email'><h3>".$column['email']."</h3></section>";
    echo "<section class='passwordUpdate'><a href='update.php?user_id=".$column['user_id']."'>Change Password</a></section>";
    echo "<section class='logout'><a href='extras/logoutProcess.php'>Logout</a></section>";
    echo "<hr />";

    echo '<section style="overflow:auto;height:400px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>';
    while($savedP = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>
                    <a target='_self' href='fullProductInfo.php?productId=".$savedP['productId']."'>
                        <img src='http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/images/products/".$savedP['productImg']."' alt='".$savedP['productName']."' width='180' height='150' border='0' />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td><a target='_self' href='fullProductInfo.php?productId=".$savedP['productId']."'>".$savedP['productName']."</a></td>
                <td>&pound;".$savedP['price']."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></section>";
}
```

Every bit of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question correct you only need a `right join` over these 3 tables.

Comment: Have looked into this and it seems like the right way to go, thank you for helping me along the correct path :)